# How do I query security related Win32_NTLogEvent in Delphi

Tags: security, delphi, logging, wmi

I'm trying to make a translation to Delphi of a VBScript code to detect login attempts, looking for wmi code in Delphi I've found this page theroadtodelphi.com that provide code and samples, of wmi querying all of them work fine but when I try the following query (the one from the script)

```
"SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' AND TargetInstance.Logfile = 'Security' AND TargetInstance.EventType = 5 AND (TargetInstance.EventIdentifier = 529 OR TargetInstance.EventIdentifier = 4625) AND (TargetInstance.SourceName = 'Security' OR TargetInstance.SourceName = 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing')"
```

It gets nothing, It seems that security events require special treatment so digging in script code I found a special way of creating wmi object:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{(security)}!root/cimv2")
' Create event sink to catch security events
Set objEventSink = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "eventSink_")
objWMIService.ExecNotificationQueryAsync objEventSink, "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' AND TargetInstance.Logfile = 'Security' AND TargetInstance.EventType = 5 AND (TargetInstance.EventIdentifier = 529 OR TargetInstance.EventIdentifier = 4625) AND (TargetInstance.SourceName = 'Security' OR TargetInstance.SourceName = 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing')"
```

I don't get a way to create wmi object with those attributes.
Can some guide me to correct path on how create wmi object in Delphi with desired attributes?

Comment: Take a look at: https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/04/18/delphi-and-wmi-events/

Comment: Already seen, no security related queries

Comment: ..and you're running Elevated with Admin rights? Because the query works using 'wbemtest.exe' run as Admin, without I get an 'Access Denied' error. Would have been better to show working code and any error messages in your post.

Comment: With and without elevation, no result at all on same machine that script works as intented (https://github.com/EvanAnderson/ts_block)